# Creating custom module in Vtiger CRM from scratch with table

Tags: php, vtiger

I am new to Vtiger CRM and I have searched a lot to find how to create a custom module in Vtiger CRM with a table associated with it from scratch. I am not able to follow the documentation provided by Vtiger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer this url for Creating New module and fields.

https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/CreatingEntityModule

Or if you having any problem then follow as per instructions.

first of all do this.

First create a new folder(module name without space) in modules and copy files from vtlib/ModuleDir/5.4.0 file to the folder created in modules/newmodule

Change name of ModuleFile.js, ModuleFile.php, ModuleFileAjax.php with your module name(with no space).

Keep in mind, During changing name of ModuleFileAjax.php just Replace ModuleFile  with name of Module.

Go to modulename.php to change the class name, $table_name (6values change), $table_index (4values change).

Create new file with any name. Insert the code below to add the fields and also module.

```
<?php 

// Turn on debugging level
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

$module = new Vtiger_Module();
$module->name = 'Store';//(No space in module name)
$module->save();

$module->initTables();
$module->initWebservice();

$menu = Vtiger_Menu::getInstance('Support');
$menu->addModule($module);

$block1 = new Vtiger_Block();
$block1->label = 'Organization Information';
$module->addBlock($block1); //to create a new block

$field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field0->name = 'organization_name';
$field0->label = 'Organization Name';
$field0->table = $module->basetable; 
$field0->column = 'organization_name';
$field0->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field0->uitype = 2;
$field0->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$module->setEntityIdentifier($field0); //to insert values in entity folder
$block1->addField($field0); //to add field in block


$field1 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field1->name = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->label = 'Store ID';
$field1->table = $module->basetable; 
$field1->column = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field1->uitype = 4;
$field1->typeofdata = 'V~O';
$block1->addField($field1);

//Do not change any value for filed2.
$field2 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field2->name = 'assigned_user_id';
$field2->label = 'Assigned To';
$field2->table = 'vtiger_crmentity'; 
$field2->column = 'smownerid';
$field2->columntype = 'int(19)';
$field2->uitype = 53;
$field2->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$block1->addField($field2);

$filter1 = new Vtiger_Filter();
$filter1->name = 'All';
$filter1->isdefault = true;
$module->addFilter($filter1);
// Add fields to the filter created
$filter1->addField($field0, 1);
$filter1->addField($field1, 2);
$filter1->addField($field2, 3);


/** Set sharing access of this module */
$module->setDefaultSharing('Private'); 
/** Enable and Disable available tools */
$module->enableTools(Array('Import', 'Export'));
$module->disableTools('Merge');



?>
```

**Updates: Supported Scripts for Vtiger 7 & Vtiger 8**

**Creating a custom module in Vtiger 7/Vtiger 8 CRM from scratch with a table**

```
<?php
// Turn on debugging level
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Package.php';
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');

$MODULENAME     = 'Store';
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);

if ($moduleInstance && file_exists('modules/' . $MODULENAME)) {    
    echo 'Store Module is exists';
}else {
  $moduleInstance             = new Vtiger_Module(); 
  $moduleInstance->name       = $MODULENAME;
  $moduleInstance->tablabel   = 'LBL_STORE';
  $moduleInstance->parent     = 'Inventory';
  $moduleInstance->save();
  
  // Schema Setup
  $moduleInstance->initTables();

  // Webservice Setup
  $moduleInstance->initWebservice();
  
  $block        = new Vtiger_Block();
  $block->label = 'LBL_STORE_INFORMATION';
  $block        = $block->getInstance($block->label, $moduleInstance);
  if ($block == false) {
      $block        = new Vtiger_Block();
      $block->label = 'LBL_STORE_INFORMATION';
      $moduleInstance->addBlock($block);
      $block        = $block->getInstance($block->label, $moduleInstance);
  }
  
  $filter = Vtiger_Filter::getInstance('All', $moduleInstance);
  if (empty($filter)) {
      // Filter Setup
      $filter            = new Vtiger_Filter();
      $filter->name      = 'All';
      $filter->isdefault = true;
      $moduleInstance->addFilter($filter);
  }
    
  //Adding fields
  $field = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('store_name', $moduleInstance);
  if (empty($field)) {
    $field              = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field->name        = 'store_name';
    $field->label       = 'LBL_STORE_NAME';
    $field->uitype      = 2;      
    $field->presence    = 1;
    $field->displaytype = 3;
    $field->column      = $field->name;
    $field->columntype  = 'VARCHAR(20)';
    $field->typeofdata  = 'V~M';
    $field->sequence    = 1;
    $field->table       = $module->basetable;
    $block->addField($field);
    
    $filter->addField($field, 1);
    
    $moduleInstance->setEntityIdentifier($field);
    echo '\n fieldname' .$field->name .'added successfully'."\n";
  }


  $field = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('store_number', $moduleInstance);
  if (empty($field)) {
    $field  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field->name        = 'store_number';
    $field->label       = 'LBL_STORE_NUMBER';
    $field->uitype      = 4;       
    $field->presence    = 2;
    $field->displaytype = 3;
    $field->column      = $field->name;
    $field->columntype  = 'VARCHAR(20)';
    $field->typeofdata  = 'V~O';
    $field->sequence    = 2;
    $field->table       = $module->basetable;
    $block->addField($field);
    
    $filter->addField($field, 2);
    echo "\n Field ".$field->name." added.\n";
  }

  $field = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('store_address', $moduleInstance);
  if (empty($field)) {
    $field  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field->name        = 'store_address';
    $field->label       = 'LBL_STORE_ADDRESS';
    $field->uitype      = 16;
    $field->presence    = 2;
    $field->displaytype = 1;
    $field->column      = $field->name;
    $field->columntype  = 'VARCHAR(20)';
    $field->typeofdata  = 'V~O';
    $field->sequence    = 3;
    $field->table       = $module->basetable;
    $block->addField($field);

    $filter->addField($field, 3);
    echo "\n Field ".$field->name." added.\n";
  }

  $field = Vtiger_Field::getInstance('assigned_to', $moduleInstance);
  if (empty($field)) {
    $field  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field->name        = 'assigned_to';
    $field->label       = 'LBL_ASSIGNED_TO';
    $field->uitype      = 16;
    $field->presence    = 2;
    $field->displaytype = 1;
    $field->column      = $field->name;
    $field->columntype  = 'VARCHAR(20)';
    $field->typeofdata  = 'V~O';
    $field->sequence    = 5;
    $field->table       = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $block->addField($field);
    
    $filter->addField($field, 4);
    echo "\n Field ".$field->name." added.\n";
  }
  
  Settings_MenuEditor_Module_Model::addModuleToApp($moduleInstance->name, $moduleInstance->parent);
  echo 'Store Module is Created';
}
?>
```

Comment: One should use the example files you specified on the vtlib folder, and also this 'any name' file with this content you provide (as an example)?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not claer with your question.

Comment: I mean, in the vtlib/ModuleDir, i change names in files as you stated in your answer, plus should i add a new .php file with the code you provide?

Comment: Ok got you. Don't rename the folder in vtlib/MOduleDir. Just copy that folder and paste it in modules folder. There you have to rename. And to add fields to that module create one file and name it any. suppose addfield.php. And put it in your project root directory. Suppose your project name is vtiger. put addfield.php file in vtiger folder. And must change the code i have provided here with your module name and filed name

Comment: Awesome, but i added the addfield.php file into the vtiger's root folder, then ran it from localhost/addfield.php, other than that everything worked! Thank you!

Comment: you have run that file from localhost/yourprojectname/addfields.php

Comment: No, just localhost/addfields.php

Answer (score 1):

we have Create Store module 
Create folder in modules/Store and also create Store.php file in Store folder

modules/Store/Store.php

```
include_once 'modules/Vtiger/CRMEntity.php';
class Store extends Vtiger_CRMEntity {
        var $table_name = 'vtiger_store';
        var $table_index= 'storeid';

        var $customFieldTable = Array('vtiger_storecf', 'storeid');

        var $tab_name = Array('vtiger_crmentity', 'vtiger_store', 'vtiger_storecf');

        var $tab_name_index = Array(
                'vtiger_crmentity' => 'crmid',
                'vtiger_store' => 'storeid',
                'vtiger_storecf'=>'storeid');

        var $list_fields = Array (
                /* Format: Field Label => Array(tablename, columnname) */
                // tablename should not have prefix 'vtiger_'
                'Organization Name' => Array('store', 'organization_name'),
                'Assigned To' => Array('crmentity','smownerid')
        );
        var $list_fields_name = Array (
                /* Format: Field Label => fieldname */
                'Organization Name' => 'organization_name',
                'Assigned To' => 'assigned_user_id',
        );

        // Make the field link to detail view
        var $list_link_field = 'organization_name';

        // For Popup listview and UI type support
        var $search_fields = Array(
                /* Format: Field Label => Array(tablename, columnname) */
                // tablename should not have prefix 'vtiger_'
                'Organization Name' => Array('store', 'organization_name'),
                'Assigned To' => Array('vtiger_crmentity','assigned_user_id'),
        );
        var $search_fields_name = Array (
                /* Format: Field Label => fieldname */
                'Organization Name' => 'organization_name',
                'Assigned To' => 'assigned_user_id',
        );

        // For Popup window record selection
        var $popup_fields = Array ('organization_name');

        // For Alphabetical search
        var $def_basicsearch_col = 'organization_name';

        // Column value to use on detail view record text display
        var $def_detailview_recname = 'organization_name';

        // Used when enabling/disabling the mandatory fields for the module.
        // Refers to vtiger_field.fieldname values.
        var $mandatory_fields = Array('organization_name','assigned_user_id');

        var $default_order_by = 'organization_name';
        var $default_sort_order='ASC';
}
```

Create languages/en_us/Store.php

```
<?php 
$languageStrings = array(
  'SINGLE_Store'=>'Store'
);
?>
```

Create file /var/www/html/Projectname/Store.php and run this file

```
<?php 
// Turn on debugging level
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

$module = new Vtiger_Module();
$module->name = 'Store';//(No space in module name)
$module->save();

$module->initTables();
$module->initWebservice();

$menu = Vtiger_Menu::getInstance('Support');
$menu->addModule($module);

$block1 = new Vtiger_Block();
$block1->label = 'Organization Information';
$module->addBlock($block1); //to create a new block

$field0 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field0->name = 'organization_name';
$field0->label = 'Organization Name';
$field0->table = $module->basetable; 
$field0->column = 'organization_name';
$field0->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field0->uitype = 2;
$field0->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$module->setEntityIdentifier($field0); //to insert values in entity folder
$block1->addField($field0); //to add field in block


$field1 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field1->name = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->label = 'Store ID';
$field1->table = $module->basetable; 
$field1->column = 'store_id_auto';
$field1->columntype = 'VARCHAR(100)';
$field1->uitype = 4;
$field1->typeofdata = 'V~O';
$block1->addField($field1);

//Do not change any value for filed2.
$field2 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field2->name = 'assigned_user_id';
$field2->label = 'Assigned To';
$field2->table = 'vtiger_crmentity'; 
$field2->column = 'smownerid';
$field2->columntype = 'int(19)';
$field2->uitype = 53;
$field2->typeofdata = 'V~M';
$block1->addField($field2);

$field3 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field3->name = 'CreatedTime';
$field3->label= 'Created Time';
$field3->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
$field3->column = 'createdtime';
$field3->uitype = 70;
$field3->typeofdata = 'T~O';
$field3->displaytype= 2;
$block->addField($field3);

$field4 = new Vtiger_Field();
$field4->name = 'ModifiedTime';
$field4->label= 'Modified Time';
$field4->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
$field4->column = 'modifiedtime';
$field4->uitype = 70;
$field4->typeofdata = 'T~O';
$field4->displaytype= 2;
$block->addField($field4);

$filter1 = new Vtiger_Filter();
$filter1->name = 'All';
$filter1->isdefault = true;
$module->addFilter($filter1);
// Add fields to the filter created
$filter1->addField($field0, 1);
$filter1->addField($field1, 2);
$filter1->addField($field2, 3);


/** Set sharing access of this module */
$module->setDefaultSharing('Private'); 
/** Enable and Disable available tools */
$module->enableTools(Array('Import', 'Export'));
$module->disableTools('Merge');

?>
```